# Create an input field in a javascript d3 group

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

i started with d3 some weeks ago, so i am kinda beginner. I created a page consisting nodes and edges. Now i want to change my node specific settings in a sidebar. Thatfor i want to create on the one hand an input field in it and on the second hand a dropdown menu to chose predefined settings.

My first problem i had with the input field. By adding it to the sidebar group by d3.select('..').append ... it is created but not visible at the page, if i create it at the html page by creating a form and putting an input inside, i can see it at the page but below my svg tag. In this case, if i change x and y coordinates nothing is changing.

So to my question. Is it possible to create an input field inside a group element in d3, best by appending it to it? If yes, how does it work. If no, what is the best solution to add it to a position at the page i can define with x and y coordinates.

My page structure looks like this at the moment, each tag inside the svg is a group element:

```
<svg>
    <graph>
    <header>
    <sidebar>
</svg>
```

and if i do this inside sidebar, it is added to the DOM but just not visible at the page:

```
var svgForm = svg.append("form")
  .attr("class", "sideBarInputForm")
  .attr("name", "myform")
  .attr("x", 500)
  .attr("y", 300);

svgForm.append("input")
  .attr("class", "sideBarInput")
  .attr("name", "Submit")
  .attr("type", "submit")
  .attr("value", "add to List")
  .attr("x", 500)
  .attr("y", 300);

svgForm.append("input")
  .attr("type", "text")
  .attr("id", "myVal")
  .attr("placeholder", "add some text..")
  .attr("x", 700)
  .attr("y", 300);
```

The x and y values are correct so this is not the problem. If i add text at this coordinates, it is displayed well.

Thank you for any help.

Greetings Frank

Comment: you can only append svg elements to svg, so html elements you can not. Unless you use foreign object which isn't widely supported. I would recommend appending the inputs to the parent of the svg. Is there a desperate need for it to appear inside the SVG ?

Comment: Well it would have made it a lot easier but i should be fine by adding it to the parent object. Thank you for your fast answer.